# How to set zsh shell title without executing command substitutions twice?

Tags: zsh, tmux, xterm

My zsh config contains `setopt PROMPT_SUBST`. When I use command substitution in a shell command, I see it is executed twice. This could cause slowdowns or even bugs in my scripting.

```
% setopt PROMPT_SUBST
% echo $(echo executed >&2)
executed
executed
```

I found it is happening due to my setting the xterm window title in `preexec()`. (Note: I'm not using xterm, but the same code works for many terminals, like WSL terminal, wslterm, and tmux.) How can I set the title in a way that doesn't execute the command substitutions? Note: the current title setting code is:

```
preexec () {
    print -Pn "\ek$2\e\\"
}
precmd () { 
    print -Pn "\ekzsh\e\\"
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `-P` in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like you'd want `print -rn $'\ek'$2$'\e\\'` here

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately all terminals are different and the only way seems to be to write a different `preexec` and `precmd` for each terminal. To get working tab titles in tmux, I had to add `set -g allow-rename on` to .tmux.conf, or to execute `tmux set -g allow-rename on`. The functions to set the title without executing the command are:

```
preexec () { 
    local cmd=$2
    printf "\033k%s\033\\" $cmd
}
precmd () {
    printf "\033kzsh\033\\"
}
```

The more comprehensive solution would need different technique for each `$TERM`. Note that tmux is not detected using `$TERM`.

```
if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
    preexec () { 
        local cmd=$2
        printf "\033k%s\033\\" $cmd
    }
    precmd () { 
        printf "\033kzsh\033\\"
    }
else
    # Set xterm/terminal/whatever titles when commands are running:
    case $TERM in
        linux)
            ;;
        *xterm*|rxvt|rxvt-unicode|rxvt-256color|(dt|k|E)term)
            preexec() {
                # TODO
            }
            precmd() {
                # TODO
            }
            ;;
        *screen*)
            preexec() {
                # TODO
            }
            precmd() {
                # TODO
            }
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Some `preexec` commands worth testing in each terminal are:

```
print -Pn "\e]0;${cmd}\a"
print -Pn "\ek${cmd}\e\\"
```

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is the format, you shouldn't put external data in there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good catch! Fixed.

Comment: [In `xterm`-like terminals](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands), it would be `printf '\033]2;%s\a' "$cmd"` to set the title. With `0`, it sets both title and icon name (which you may or may not want).